# How do I invert the swimming controls in GTA V on PC?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I'm playing GTA V on PC with an Xbox 360 controller. How do I invert the swimming controls so that pressing Up on the Left Stick moves up while swimming, and vice versa for going down?

I only saw an option for "Invert Look", but I think that's just for looking around with the Right Stick?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to invert the controls for swimming. After a while you will get used to it, but I do agree that the game could do with an invert option for swimming.

Comment: Personally I find it way easier to swim in FPS mode than get used with that awful control. Sure, FPS mode's FOV is bad as hell, but it's not like we're fighting in the water.